# How to make async generator with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, generator

I'm trying to implement an asynchronous generator called get_all_by_chunk() to fetch data from my database in chunks using SQLAlchemy and AsyncSession. However, the current implementation does not work as expected.

```
class BaseDAO(Generic[Model]):
    def __init__(self, model: Type[Model], session: AsyncSession):
        self.model = model
        self.session = session

    ...

    async def get_all_by_chunk(self, chunk_size=10_000):
        result = await self.session.execute(
            select(self.model).yield_per(chunk_size)
        )
        async for row in result.scalars():
            yield row
```

In result: *TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression*

How can I correctly implement the get_all_by_chunk method as an asynchronous generator to fetch data from the table in chunks using SQLAlchemy and AsyncSession?

python 3.11/sqlalchemy 2.0.13

Comment: what sqlachemy version are you on?

Comment: sqlalchemy 2.0.13

Comment: on the same version I get `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'yield_per'` can you verify that? can you also try `result = await (self.session.stream(select(self.model).execution_options(yield_per=chunk_size)))` instead of what you have?

Comment: you a correct, there is no yeld_from in Select object

Comment: I noticed you posted your solution, what was wrong with the suggestion I gave?

Comment: Your suggestion is good. However, with your approach, I can retrieve objects one at a time, not in chunks. I'm also unsure about the purpose of the chunk_size attribute in your suggestion.

Btw, I added a new func 'get_iterator' in my BaseDAO with streaming

Comment: "I'm also unsure about the purpose of the chunk_size", I just converted what you had to what I thought was a solution, I assumed you knew what you were doing with that

Comment: maybe I am not understanding this properly, your question asks for a certain thing, but your answer suggests "how to get by offset and limit"

Comment: where you hoping "chunk size" would give you "chunk_size" objects per iteration? If so, then your exaction was wrong, chunk size is used to fetch"chunk_size" many rows from the database using I guess a server side cursor (not sure if its server or client side), maybe this is where the confusion was

Answer (score 1):

other solution:

```
async def get_iterator(self, *whereclauses, chunk_size: int=10_000):
    stmt = select(self.model)
    if whereclauses:
        stmt = stmt.where(*whereclauses)
    result = await (self.session.stream(stmt.execution_options(yield_per=chunk_size)))
    return result.scalars()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async def get_many(self, *whereclauses, options: Iterable | ExecutableOption = None, limit: int = None,
                   offset: int = None, order_by=None):
    stmt = select(self.model)

    if whereclauses:
        stmt = stmt.where(*whereclauses)
    if options:
        if isinstance(options, ExecutableOption):
            stmt = stmt.options(options)
        elif isinstance(options, Iterable):
            stmt = stmt.options(*options)
    if limit:
        stmt = stmt.limit(limit)
    if offset:
        stmt = stmt.offset(offset)
    if order_by:
        stmt = stmt.order_by(order_by)
    result = await self.session.execute(stmt)
    return result.scalars().all()

async def get_chunk_iterator(self, *whereclauses, chunk_size: int):
    offset = 0  # Start from the beginning

    while True:
        # Get the next batch of records
        records = await self.get_many(*whereclauses, limit=chunk_size, offset=offset, order_by=self.model.id)

        # If no more records, stop
        if not records:
            break

        # Yield the records
        yield records

        # Update the offset for the next batch
        offset += chunk_size
```

update! order_by is necessarily